# Implementing Atomic Transactions in Firestore and Flutter: How to Avoid Duplication of Logic and Code - Maintain functions with Single Responsibility

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, architecture, nosql

Suppose an application has 3 entities:

- Employee;
- Customer;
- Customer List.

And two main functionalities:

- F1) Create Customer;
- F2) Create Customer List.

The operating conditions are:

- C1) An Employee can have at most 1 Customer List.
- C2) When adding a Customer to the application, the Customer is created (F1).
- C3) If an Employee does not have a Customer List and adds a Customer, the Customer is created (F1) and a Customer List (F2) is also created for that Employee.
- C4) If both actions (F1 and F2) occur simultaneously, as happens in condition C3, both must be completed successfully. If one fails, no changes are saved in Firestore.

To ensure that both actions are successfully completed or none (in compliance with condition C4), I am using a Firestore transaction.

**However, this presents a challenge: when condition C3 is triggered, the F1 functionality is executed. To fulfill condition C4, it is necessary to integrate the F2 functionality within the F1 function. This results in the duplication of the logic and specific code for F2, in order to ensure that the transaction is correctly carried out.**

**Here is a simple illustration:**
[Simple illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNPUS.png)

Here is a code snippet, for demonstration:

```
class Employee {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String customerListId;

Employee({
  required this.id,
  required this.name,
  required this.customerListId,
  });
}

class CustomerList {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String creatorEmployeeId;
  final String creatorEmployeeName;
  final List<String> customerIds;
  final List<String> employeesWithAccessIds;

CustomerList({
  required this.id,
  required this.name,
  required this.creatorEmployeeId,
  required this.creatorEmployeeName,
  required this.customerIds,
  required this.employeesWithAccessIds,
  });
}

class Customer {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final List<String> customerListsIds;

Customer({
  required this.id,
  required this.name,
  required this.customerListsIds,
  });
}

class FirestoreServiceSimplifiedExample {
  Future<void> createCustomerF1({
  required String customerName,
  required String creatorEmployeeId,
}) async {
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  try {
  // Fetch the creator employee's updated data using the Employee model
  DocumentSnapshot creatorEmployeeSnapshot =
      await firestore.collection('employees').doc(creatorEmployeeId).get();
  if (!creatorEmployeeSnapshot.exists) {
    throw Exception("Employee with ID $creatorEmployeeId does not exist.");
  }
  var creatorEmployeeData = creatorEmployeeSnapshot.data();
  Employee creatorEmployee = Employee(
    id: creatorEmployeeId,
    name: creatorEmployeeData['name'],
    customerListId: creatorEmployeeData['customerListId'],
  );

  // Check if the employee's customerListId is empty
  bool needsNewCustomerList = creatorEmployee.customerListId.isEmpty;

  // Generate a new CustomerList ID if needed
  String? newListId;
  if (needsNewCustomerList) {
    newListId = firestore.collection('customerLists').doc().id;
  }

  // Prepare the new Customer instance
  final String newCustomerId = firestore.collection('customers').doc().id;
  final Customer newCustomer = Customer(
    id: newCustomerId,
    name: customerName,
    customerListsIds: needsNewCustomerList ? [newListId!] : [],
  );

  await firestore.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    // Add the new Customer to the collection
    transaction.set(firestore.collection('customers').doc(newCustomerId), {
      'id': newCustomerId,
      'name': newCustomer.name,
      'customerListsIds': newCustomer.customerListsIds,
    });

    // Create and add the new CustomerList to the collection if needed
    if (needsNewCustomerList) {
      transaction
          .set(firestore.collection('customerLists').doc(newListId), {
        'id': newListId,
        'name': creatorEmployee
            .name, // List name is the creator employee's name
        'creatorEmployeeId': creatorEmployeeId,
        'creatorEmployeeName': creatorEmployee.name,
        'customerIds': [newCustomerId],
        'employeesWithAccessIds': [
          creatorEmployeeId
        ], // Add creator employee to the list
      });

      // Update the Employee's customerListId
      transaction.update(
          firestore.collection('employees').doc(creatorEmployeeId), {
        'customerListId': newListId,
      });
    }
  });
} catch (e) {
  print("An error occurred: $e");
}
}

Future<void> createCustomerListF2({
  required String listName,
  required String creatorEmployeeId,
}) async {
final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

try {
  // Fetch the creator employee's data using the Employee model
  DocumentSnapshot creatorEmployeeSnapshot =
      await firestore.collection('employees').doc(creatorEmployeeId).get();
  if (!creatorEmployeeSnapshot.exists) {
    throw Exception("Employee with ID $creatorEmployeeId does not exist.");
  }
  var creatorEmployeeData = creatorEmployeeSnapshot.data();
  Employee creatorEmployee = Employee(
    id: creatorEmployeeId,
    name: creatorEmployeeData['name'],
    customerListId: creatorEmployeeData['customerListId'],
  );

  // Generate a new CustomerList ID
  String newListId = firestore.collection('customerLists').doc().id;

  await firestore.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    // Add the new CustomerList to the collection
    transaction.set(firestore.collection('customerLists').doc(newListId), {
      'id': newListId,
      'name': listName,
      'creatorEmployeeId': creatorEmployeeId,
      'creatorEmployeeName': creatorEmployee.name,
      'customerIds': [],
      'employeesWithAccessIds': [creatorEmployeeId],
    });

    // Update the Employee's customerListId
    transaction
        .update(firestore.collection('employees').doc(creatorEmployeeId), {
      'customerListId': newListId,
    });
  });
} catch (e) {
  print("An error occurred: $e");
}
}
}
```

So,

**How can I avoid this logic and code duplication with Firestore and maintain functions with a “Single Responsibility” without losing transaction "atomicity"?**

Is this a limitation of NoSQL, where I can't do much? Or are there ways to avoid these situations?

Ps: This is a very simplified example to make it more clear, that logic implementation can be replicated in several functions and in different use cases, as a consequence of the database denormalization and structure, to ensure that the transactions works properly and prevent data anomalies.

Comment: Did you try C4? I mean complete F1 and fail F2? AFAIK, the transaction works on only one collection and not different ones. It's not a relational database and cross collection constraint and transaction does not exist (again AFAIK!)

Comment: Yes, I tried C4, with the transaction implementation, it works as it should. The transaction works with different collections. NoSQL databases do not require constraints and relationships, but they do exist, and are used to avoid data anomalies, as you can see [here](https://hackolade.com/help/Relationshipsanddenormalization.html). And these transactions with duplicate logic were a consequence of the database denormalization, this example I used was just to make it more intuitive, because this happens in various different use cases.

Comment: Hmm thanks, I always used it on one collection!

Comment: To solve your issue, I will do it in 2 API call. If F2 fail, I will retry, and then delete F1. If you can call F2 from 2 point, from inside and outside the transaction, you can't put it in the transaction. You need a best effort business rules

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, the issue with making two API calls is that in this scenario, if there's a chance of failure in F1 or F2, there's also a risk that the "rollback" call for F1 might fail. I have updated the question with more details and included a code snippet for demonstration.

Comment: Agree. That's why I mentioned "best effort". You can also "soft delete F1" and add a deleted field to true. Then, have a batch process that delete all the soft deleted F1 every night (kind of garbage collector). I know that's code overhead, but sometime, there isn't straightforward solution!

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of doing it that way. Now I need to see to what extent it is more advantageous and less costly to do this. Checking this seems like a complex task, but thank you very much! I remain open to new alternatives.